# Possible to define SortMemberPath conditionally with Converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, converters

I have a DataGrid of which contains a column that is shared by 2 different sortable items in a StackPanel.

These items are both for NameA/NameB and what I want is for the SortMemberPath to change between these two depending on the state of a bool called 'sortByNameB'.

What I was thinking was using a converter with static resource which checks the state of sortByNameB and then returns something to SortMemberPath.. but I'm not sure what should be returned? I tried returning string as "NameA"/"NameB" but this just breaks the sorting.

Relevant XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Names" SortMemberPath="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NameSort}}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Padding="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=NameA}" RequestNavigate="Name_RequestNavigate">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameA}" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource FGName}}"/>
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Padding="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=NameA}" RequestNavigate="Name_RequestNavigate">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameB}" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource FGName}}"/>
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Converter:

```
public class NameSort : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return (ToolView.sortByNameB) ? "NameB" : "NameA";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a method of how to do it.

I have a Checkbox which controls the state of sortByNameB and for the sake of this example the DataGrid is named "dataGrid", in the Checked/Unchecked events add:

```
string toSortBy = (sortByNameB) ? "NameB" : "NameA";
dataGrid.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(1).SortMemberPath = toSortBy;
```

Where '1' is the column index of the Name column.

Not sure if this is a really elegant way of doing it, would have liked to do it through a binding in xaml, but it's simple at least.

Comment: Is sortByNameB a DependencyProperty? Or does the DataContext implement INPC? If not, it will not trigger the converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you hardcode "NameA", does the sorting work? If so, then the converter will work since its returning the same thing, something else is going wrong.

Your SortMemberPath should be bound to Path=sortByNameB, Converter=... though. Right now its just bound to the object itself, so you aren't going to call the converter when sortByNameB changes, which I think is what you mean by "breaks the sorting"?

Comment: The sorting does indeed work if I put SortMemberPath="NameA" or NameB. I tried {Binding Path=sortByNameB, Converter={StaticResource NameSort}} but it's not working. By "breaks the sorting" I mean the column does not appear to allow a click.. it doesn't sort at all and it doesn't respond at all to a click. I tried adding console output to the converter and nothing appears in console so it's not even calling the converter?